# How can I specify a shared library reference at the web module level in Websphere 6.1 deployment descriptors?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I am working on a web application that is deployed to Websphere as a war file contained inside a wrapper ear. There are no other modules within the ear. A shared library has been created at the cell scope in the Websphere admin console, and I can specify a shared library reference at the web module level in the admin console. Everything works great when I do this, until I undeploy and redeploy the application, which of course causes the shared library reference to disappear.

I would like to specify the shared library reference in the deployment descriptors for the war or ear, but I'm not sure how to do this at the web module level. Does anyone know if a shared library reference can be specified at the web module level via deployment descriptors in the war or ear file?

EDIT: this screenshot shows the shared library reference that was created in the admin console. My goal is to have the same shared library reference created via deployment descriptors, so that each time the app is undeployed and redeployed the shared library reference does not need to be recreated in the admin console.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't specify shared library dependencies in the deployment descriptor, but you can specify them in MANIFEST.MF using [Installed Optional Packages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tcws_installoptpkg.html) support